# Google Finance Chart Zoom not working

Tags: google-finance

If I pick a stock, say Ferrari, and view it's stock price chart at [Google Finance](https://www.google.com/finance?chdnp=1&chdd=1&chds=1&chdv=1&chvs=maximized&chdeh=0&chfdeh=0&chdet=1465399560000&chddm=55770&chls=IntervalBasedLine&q=BIT%3ARACE&&ei=hhBYV9myK9KU0ATStKSYCA), and click on different zoom levels, e.g. 5y or 10y, the chart does not update.

This occurs in Chrome and Internet Explorer on 2 different PCs.

I think I am misunderstanding the way Zoom works?

If clicking on the different zoom levels is supposed to dynamically update the chart, what can I do to ensure this works.

I have no similar issues on different websites, and JavaScript is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time range exceeding the range for which the data are available has the same effect as "All". In the case of Ferrari, this includes the 1y and 5y ranges, since the company has become independent in January 2016.

Pick a stock symbol with a longer price record, such as MSFT, to see that both 1y and 5y zoom levels indeed work.

Answer (score -2):

I entered `about:plugins` in my Chrome browser and selected "always run" for the Flash Player, and restarted Chrome.

I'm not sure which did the trick, restarting Chrome or activating Flash Player, but it worked for me.